# Are these two extension fields isomorphic?

Tags: abstract-algebra, extension-field, irreducible-polynomials

Consider $f(x) = x^2 + 1$ and $g(x) = x^2 + 4$, two irreducible polynomials in $\mathbb{Z}_3 [x]$. Let $\alpha$ and $\beta$ be a zero of $f(x)$ and $g(x)$, respectively. Are $\mathbb{Z}_3 (\alpha)$ and $\mathbb{Z}_3 (\beta)$ isomorphic?

I think the answer is yes, because any irreducible polynomial in $\mathbb{Z}_3 [x]$ is just each polynomail "shifted" by 3, right? Which means all extension fields would behave similarly, and hence be isomorphic. Is my line of thinking correct? Thank you.

Comment: Yes; $x^2 + 1$ and $x^2+4$ are the same polynomial even since $1 = 4$ in $\mathbb{Z}_3$.

Comment: Beyond what basket said, you can forget that they are literally the same polynomial. Both extensions have cardinality nine. Finite fields of the same cardinality are isomorphic. 

Any splitting field of an irreducible quadratic over $\mathbb{Z}_3$ will have cardinality $9$ and hence be isomorphic to what you listed. An example would be the splitting field over $\mathbb{Z}_3$ of $x^2 + 2x + 2$.

Comment: the question sounds strange a little bit, because $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ are not just equal, it is just one element in $\mathbb{Z}_3[x]$, because you have no $4$ in $\mathbb{Z}_3$. Btw, I'd like to give you more interesting example, in my view. You can take smth like $x^2-x+1$, which has two roots in $\mathbb{C}$ and notice that $\mathbb{R}(\alpha)$, $\mathbb{R}(\beta)$ and $\mathbb{R}[x]/<x^2-x+1>$ are all isomorphic. And this is the general law)